# Is there an equation to find the tangent of an inclined ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

There is a point (x,y) in the elliptical orbit inclined at theta angle.
I know the x, y coordinates and the center coordinates and Major Minor.
In this case, is there an equation to find the tangent line?

Comment: If you have angle of inclination, center and axes you can write the equation of the ellipse. Once you have the equation, use implicit differentiation to find the slope of a tangent line. Finally, find equation of a tangent that goes thru a particular point.

Comment: (h,k) = Center and theta=17 ● a=400/2 ● b=314/2 ● h=500 ● k=500 ● x=308.739049 ● y= 441.525659 ● ((x-h)*Cos(theta)+(y-k)*Sin(theta))^2/a^2 + (-(x-h)*Sin(theta)+(y-k)*Cos(theta))^2/b^2=1  ● Q=(1/a)*((x-h)*Cos(theta)+(y-k)*Sin(theta))  ●  R=(1/b)*(-(x-h)*Sin(theta)+(y-k)*Cos(theta)) ● x=a*Q*Cos(theta)-b*R*Sin(theta)+h = 308.739049  ● y=a*Q*Sin(theta)+b*R*Cos(theta)+k = 441.525659 ● Tangent_Angle=ATan(  b*Q / (-a*R)  )+theta = -73

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is the center, $\theta$ the angle of inclination and $a,b$ the semi-axes lengths, the equation would be $$\frac{((x-x(S)) \cos{\theta}+(y-y(S)) \sin{\theta})^2}{a^2}+\frac{(-(x-x(S)) \sin{\theta}+(y-y(S))\cos{\theta})^2}{b^2}=1,$$ and the tangent at $(h,k)$ is given from the expanded form $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$ by the usual $Axh+B(xk+yh)+Cyk+D(x+h)+E(y+k)+F=0.$

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart. I searched the websites of various countries around the world and found this way. (h,k) = Center and theta=17 ● a=400/2 ● b=314/2 ● h=500 ● k=500 ● x=308.739049 ● y= 441.525659 ● ((x-h)*Cos(theta)+(y-k)*Sin(theta))^2/a^2 + (-(x-h)*Sin(theta)+(y-k)*Cos(theta))^2/b^2=1  ● Q=(1/a)*((x-h)*Cos(theta)+(y-k)*Sin(theta))  ●  R=(1/b)*(-(x-h)*Sin(theta)+(y-k)*Cos(theta)) ● x=a*Q*Cos(theta)-b*R*Sin(theta)+h = 308.739049  ● y=a*Q*Sin(theta)+b*R*Cos(theta)+k = 441.525659 ● Tangent_Angle=ATan(  b*Q / (-a*R)  )+theta = -73

Comment: @AmourMath The above method [in geogebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZmD0.png) gives the same result.

Comment:  Oh, yep : ) Thank you for showing me the way : )